# Problem with running stable diffusion and getting torch to recognize my Graphics card for the CUDA test

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, stable-diffusion

so I've been trying to install Stable diffusion on my computer for the past three days. My computer has a gtx 980, and I have an i7 4790K cpu. I installed my Windows 10 OS on a smaller SSD that I have, while I install almost all games and programs on my other 2TB harddisk. So I think I might have installed Python 3.10.6 on my Harddisk drive (D:), while my scripts are located in appdata on my OS drive (C:).

When I run the webui-user.bat, I get this:

> File "D:\SDlocal\launch.py", line 64, in un raise
> RuntimeError(message) RuntimeError: Error running command. Command:
> "D:\SDlocal\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import torch; assert
> torch.cuda.is_available(), 'Torch is not able to use GPU; add
> --skip-torch-cuda-test to COMMANDLINE_ARGS variaable to disable this check'"

I Tried following the advice, and added the skip CUDA test to the commandline args in webui-user, but the next error that showed up was:

> Installing requirements for Web UI
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\SDlocal\launch.py", line 306, in 
> prepare_environment()
> File "D:\SDlocal\launch.py", line 258, in prepare_environment
> run_pip(f"install -r {requirements_file}", "requirements for WebUI")
> File "D:\SDlocal\launch.py", line 93, in run_pip
> return run(f'"{python}" -m pip {args} --prefer-binary{index_url_line}', desc=f"Installing {desc}", errdesc=f"Couldn't install {desc}")
> File "D:\SDlocal\launch.py", line 64, in run
> raise RuntimeError(message)
> RuntimeError: Couldn't install requirements for Web UI.
> Command: "D:\SDlocal\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install -r requirements_versions.txt --prefer-binary
> Error code: 1
> stdout:

I looked into the launch.py and managed to find that it tries to build an environment and install a specific CUDA and torch version, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to start tinkering with the launch.py file, so I'd like to set up a proper environment to launch python files from my D: drive first, and make sure that it's not my weird setup that's the problem.

As a sidenote, I've looked up the compatible CUDA version, but it failed to run the torch.cuda.is_available(), but I found another thread that helped me look up the proper compatibility between CUDA, my graphics driver as well as the Torch version, and when I installed CUDA 11.6 and the 527,37 graphics driver for my card, I was able to get torch.cuda.is_available() to return true, but whenever I try to launch the webui-user.bat file, It still returns the error that it can't get past the CUDA test.

Thanks for any help regarding this matter, I'm starting to lose the will to continue looking into this matter, but I'm willing to provide any other information you'd need to help me further through this process.

Oh wait, I didn't realize there were 2 parts to the question itself. I've already described the situation, so I'll just write some filler here.

Comment: Exactly the same issue here, I did see something that said only RTX cards worked, but that just "some guy" in  a forum, nothing official.